# Can undead creatures (raised by a necromancy spell) climb a rope, climb a ladder, or swim?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, undead, necromancy

I'm thinking about making a Necromancy wizard, but had a few questions about RAW.

Would undead from the *animate undead* spell (or any necromancer spells), e.g. skeletons or zombies, be able to climb a rope, climb a ladder, or swim?

I feel like they would be able to climb a ladder, the rope is a little iffy, and swimming would be a no.

That said, I haven't found any restrictions or parameters in the PHB or DMG that mention those rules.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### There are no secret rules

These creatures have a speed and “[movement can include jumping, climbing, and swimming.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition)”

There is nothing in their stat blocks that says they can’t nor is there anything specific to undead that says they can’t. So they can.

Now, in your game you can make this rule because the rules say you can override the rules.

Comment: That makes sense! I just wanted to check and see, that way I won't be leaving my undead posse at every turn. Asked the DM to make sure, and they said they didn't have this come up before either.